# Simple casting or combining int

Tags: java, android, casting

I am new to android programming from iOS. I can't seem to figure this out and it seems pretty simple. I want to call a method and send it a number and have it play a certain sound depending on the number. I have about 100 sounds so when I tap on a row in a ListView I want to call this method. How do I make num attached to "sound"

```
playSound(1);

void playSound(int num) {
String string = new String("R.raw.sound"+ num);  
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(string);
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, myUri);
}
```

Comment: I think if you pass different numbers from 1-100, if will use that in the `num` variable inside the function.

Comment: Do you mean that you have 100 sounds and you want to access them based on the integer parameter passed?

Comment: Yes. I have 100 sounds and I want to pass an integer, and depending on the integer I want to play one of the hundred sounds. If I passed the number 24 I want to play the file named: sound24

Answer (score 0):

For ListView it is

**Initialization**

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vmf_items_list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(LstListener);
```

**OnItemClickListener**

```
private OnItemClickListener LstListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                   int Pos=position;
                   //your method

    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, but then I need to be able to load one out of 100 sounds depending on what that int is. How do I make R.raw.sound + Pos?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("sound"+num, "raw", getPackageName());
```

to get sound ID and pass it to method

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, id);
```

Comment: It is not working, I think I have to use a Uri instead of an int.

Comment: This is working, when I copy and pasted your code I forgot to change the word "sound" to the actual name. I'm a dummy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hop you've solved your problem. But, if all the above answers method didn't work for you, there are few methods which you might try and are are coming to my mind. They might help you.

**Method 1:**

One alternate way can be to save the names of the 100 songs in `array.xml` file. Something like:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="song_names">        
        <item>song_name1</item>
        <item>song_name2</item>  
        <item>song_name3</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then you can get the array and choose the `ith` name from there.
    // in onCreate() or somewhere outside the function
    String[] allSongNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.song_names);

```
//Get ith name based on your parameter
void playSound(int num) {
    String string = allSongNames[num];  
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(string);
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, myUri);
}
```

**Method 2:**

There might be an alternate if you don't want to store 100 names in the array. I'm assuming that you've named your 100 songs in some pattern. So, assuming its like `song_name1` , `song_name3` , `song_name3`...

You have can just one string in `string.xml`:
    song_name

Then you get concatenate that string to the `num` value to pass:

```
String songNameIni = res.getString(R.string.initial_song_name);
void playSound(int num) {
    String fullSongName = songNameIni + String.valueOf(num);  
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(fullSongName);
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, myUri);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bob: Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and trying to help, but I am not understanding how your examples would help. I need to be able to get: R.raw.alarm0 where the number can be 0-100 and put it in: mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.alarm0);